# Node and RxJs: How can I avoid a memory leak on a long process?

Tags: node.js, memory, memory-leaks, rxjs

#### I'm programming a process that will take a long time running and I'm looking to optimize used memory

I have an stream of data that comes over time and I want a way to clean up this data and declared variables when the stream completes. Any ideas?

I have setted up a quick example of the problem:

```
var source = Rx.Observable.interval(100)
                         .take(20)
                         .map((x) => {
                             let onlyTrash = _.range(1000000);
                             return x;
                         });

let subscription = source.subscribe(
    x => console.log(getMemoryUsage()),
    err => console.log('Error: ' + err),
    () => console.log('Completed: ' + getMemoryUsage())
);
```

I can not show this in a Fiddle because it's referencing to process to get memory usage

If you run this example you will notice that memory usage is increasing in each tick but It doesn't decrease on completion, **this is the problem**.

Here is a example of the getMemoryUsage function if you want to try it in your node

```
var lastMemoryUsageRegister;
function getMemoryUsage() : string {
    var memoryUsage : string;
    if (!lastMemoryUsageRegister) {
        memoryUsage = process.memoryUsage().rss.toString();
    } else {
        let diff = process.memoryUsage().rss - lastMemoryUsageRegister;
        memoryUsage = (diff > 0 ? '+' : '') + diff;
    }
    lastMemoryUsageRegister = process.memoryUsage().rss;
    return memoryUsage;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap your 'trash' in a another Observable and make use of Disposable to clean up, like this:

```
.flatMap((x) => {

  return Rx.Observable.create(obs => {
    let onlyTrash = _.range(1000000);

    let disposable = Rx.Disposable.create(() => {
      onlyTrash = undefined; // free up reference
    });

    obs.onNext(x); 
    obs.onCompleted();

    return disposable;
  });

});
```

Make sure you change it to `flatMap` rather than just `map`